# Is it safe to iterate a pointer to the next blob of data in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Say we have many different structures of data which are all having a struct Header as first member. Suppose the header and the different blobs are of some arbitrary sizes. **Is it then true or false to assume that iterating the pointer to any of those structs *as a struct Header pointer* will result in the address of the next member of that struct?** And how do the C data alignment requirements come and play in such scenarios? (Can eventual slop lead to bad pointers when casting for example?)

Edit: Updated the example [as suggested by Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492136/is-it-safe-to-iterate-a-pointer-to-the-next-blob-of-data-in-c?noredirect=1#comment66302918_39492136) with working code that shows (at least on my system) that the padding makes the pointer offset of the target, and thus also implies that the answer to my main question is "false". Thank you for the relevant answers anyway!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Header {
    char data_b;
};

struct Data {
    struct Header header;
    int data;
};

void *Header_skip(void *big_or_small) {
    return (struct Header *)big_or_small + 1;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    struct Data x = { .data = 2 };
    int *data = (int *)Header_skip(&x);

    printf("Expected: %p\n", &x.data);
    printf("Actual:   %p\n", data);
    printf("Offset:   %lld\n", (long long)data - (long long)&x.data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No. `Header` field might be padded, so `any_struct + 1` will point to the beginning of this padding.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Let apart padding, etc., dereferencing the returned pointer as anything else than type `Header` **and** having a `Header` at that address invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Olaf Updated the question, thank you for the links!

Comment: ` data: 2` is not standard C! It is a gcc extension which they state themselves being obsolete since ca. 17 years now. Don't use proprietary extensions if there are identical standard ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it then true or false to assume that iterating the pointer to any of those structs as a struct Header pointer will result in the address of the next member of that struct?

It is not safe to make such an assumption.  C implementations are allowed to put arbitrary amounts of padding between struct members (in a manner that is consistent for any given struct type).  Thus, roughly speaking, your function could produce a pointer to padding, rather than a pointer to the member following the header.

> And how do the C data alignment requirements come and play in such scenarios? (Can eventual slop lead to bad pointers when casting for example?)

C implementations typically use alignment requirements in determining how much padding, if any, to insert between members, but the standard does not require them to do so, nor in general does it constrain how implementations make that decision.

Answer (score 3):

In the general case you cannot assume that incrementing the address of a `struct` member gives the address of the next member, as there may be padding between the members (e.g., for memory alignment reasons). You can use `offsetof` to determine the exact offset of the desired member.

Comment: I think `offsetof` is not useful here, as the OP wants to get not the known member, but the next one after the known one.

Comment: Which would require to pass that offset and treat the pointer as `char *`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. To access any following members their type must be known as well (or the address would be useless as it could not be cast into a pointer of the correct type), so `offsetof` can be applied to a `struct` consisting of the `Header` and those following members that will be accessed.